# What is the definition of a Critical Point?

Tags: calculus

I was reading a book on Calculus, by Michael Spivak. There they mention that points where the derivative is equal to zero are called critical points. They nowhere mention that where the derivative does not exist will be a critical point. When I Googled it, they say critical points are those where the function derivative is either zero or the derivative does not exist. Which definition should I take?

Comment: Different people use the term in somewhat different ways.

Comment: my question is whom to believe, apostol calculus ... there also it is not given that where the derivative is not defined, those are also critical points. I was making short notes and I want to follow a book where they give all the definition which are correct and universally accepted.

Comment: As intimated above, "critical point" is not one of those "universally accepted" terms.

Comment: as fas as an exam is concerned... what should i tell my students, when I am not very sure about the same.

Comment: One more question I would like to ask, as continuity is defined at an end point of a closed interval, why differentiability is not defined in the same way.

Comment: Define a critical point as a point where a function may have a minimum or a maximum.  Now discuss several cases.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe No, that's a really bad idea, leading to considerable confusion.  There are critical points that are not minima or maxima.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Please excuse my poor English, but what you've pointed out is exactly what I meant: a critical point is a point where an extremum *might* occur.

Comment: "Might" is too vague to use in definitions.

Answer (score 3):

When the derivative is 0 at a point $(x,y)$, that point is critical. When a derivative does not exist, there might be no single point that can be labeled as critical. For example, the function $x, x\in (-\infty, 0)$ and $x+3, x\in [0, \infty)$. The derivative does not exist at $x=0$, however there is no single point that can be labeled as critical. So in my opinion, if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $ exists, then that is a critical point.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, different writers define *critical point* differently:

1. Many/most define it to be either a point where the derivative is $0$ OR where the derivative doesn't exist (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)), [Paul's Online Notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/criticalpoints.aspx), [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/critical-point/)).
2. Some define it to be a point where the derivative is $0$ (e.g. [Adams](https://www.pearsoncanada.ca/media/highered-showcase/9780321880215/04_ch04_adam.pdf), [Knill](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eknill/teaching/math1a2020/handouts/lecture11.pdf), [Spivak](https://books.google.com/books?id=7JKVu_9InRUC&pg=PA187)).

So, if you're using Spivak, you should use Spivak's definition (2).